# How to tell robots that site is viewable on mobile phones?

Tags: web-development, mobile

Is there any markup or meta-tag which I can place in the pages of my website to tell crawlers which pages are either for web or for mobile?

Comment: Is this a separate mobile site, or do you use responsive design?

Answer (score 1):

Basically on a main website you should use metatag:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="http://phone.example.com/page.html" />
```

Where <kbd>http://phone.example.com/page.html</kbd> is an URL to mobile version of a page user is viewing right now. That's probably the easiest way to solve things. But in general you should use responsive design.

You can get more information on Google Support:

- [Supporting Smartphones and Feature Phones](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/feature-phones)